# How to add sass loader for node_modules in vue.config.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli, sass-loader

I am trying use sass loader for node modules. But no matter what I try, the following error occurs:

> SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.

My vue.config.js look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        sourceMap: true,
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: `
          @import "~@/my-node-module/theme/engine.scss"; 
        `
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, from the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules):

```
@import "~my-node-module/theme/engine.scss";
```

The `~` tells Webpack that the import path is not a relative path.

The `@` is a Vue CLI 3+ alias for the `src` directory.

So `~@` is essentially the same as `@`. Either way, Webpack knows the path is not relative and checks the `src` directory, and won't find the node module.

The `~` by itself causes Webpack to look elsewhere, usually `node_modules`.

## Project `.scss` file

If you had a `.scss` asset in your `src > assets > scss` directory, for example, you could do this:

```
@import '@/assets/scss/variables.scss';
```

Or this:

```
@import '~@/assets/scss/variables.scss';
```

Or even this:

```
@import '~/../src/assets/scss/variables.scss';
```